# Get values from a .txt

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a file.txt like this:

This is only a part of the .txt file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>GeoServer Configuration</title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
<body>

Workspaces
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://xxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap1.html">worldmap1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://xxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap2.html">worldmap2</a>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It´s possible to get the value ? I´m trying to pass the .txt to a .xml file but I have some problems because is not a well formed xml.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try out XmlDocument.Load

Comment: which value do you mean? And I think this is valid xml.

Comment: do you need to transform this .txt file in a well formed .xml file? or are you just interested in the values from the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to add a root element. Let's suppose you create an XML file named `TextFile1.xml`
which contains the below XML

```
<Item>
<li>
  <a href="http://10.80.14.188:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap1.html">worldmap1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="http://10.80.14.188:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap2.html">worldmap2</a>
</li>
</Item>
```

[image]

you can do the below to get the href value

```
public static class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"TextFile1.xml");
            XNamespace p = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
            var result = from item in xmldoc.Descendants(p + "a")
                         select item;

            foreach (var item in result.ToList())
            {
                string href = item.Attribute("href").Value;
                var splitHref = href.Split('/');
                string page = splitHref[splitHref.Length - 1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Massimiliano, I´m trying your code but in the foreach is not entering

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have posted an image while I'm debugging the attached code

Comment: I get that result is Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: are you using the same XML I have posted?

Comment: Yes, copy and paste from your code ( I can´t see your image) I´m copying from your code

Comment: Massimiliano, take a look at the question I paste the entire .txt file

Comment: Yes!! very near I wanna get the value worldmap1 and I´m getting <a href="http://xxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap1.html"> I suppose that with trim or another similar I´ll get Thanks Massimiliano

Comment: I have edited my question. Of course you need to improve this code 
it is just "draft" version. If you need help contact me on chat please

Comment: I've got it. Thanks Massimiliano for the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only input you have, you could change it into a valid xml document by adding a root node:

```
<root>
  <li><a href="http://10.80.14.188:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap1.html">worldmap1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://10.80.14.188:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/worldmap2.html">worldmap2</a></li>
</root>
```

(This is easy to do with some simple string concatenation)

The document is now well-formed XML, hence you ca use Linq to XML or any other XML APIs to read the values you require.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a root node seems the solution but if you cannot change the input, you can use regular expressions.

Comment: Thaks Zafer but is a txt that I get after a request